# order by clause not showing expected result

Tags: sql, oracle

when i run the following query where i need to use trim function on date,
the order of output is not proper

```
  select trim(man_date_created)as createddate,count(*) recordcount
  from man 
  where man_date_created>sysdate-15 
  group by trim(man_date_created) ORDER BY createddate;
```

this the out put i am getting from this query

```
01-APR-16
02-APR-16
03-APR-16
04-APR-16
05-APR-16
06-APR-16
07-APR-16
08-APR-16
09-APR-16
10-APR-16
11-APR-16
27-MAR-16
28-MAR-16
29-MAR-16
30-MAR-16
31-MAR-16
```

where you can see that after 11 april its showing entries of march.
  is there any solution for this so that i cant get the count of all status?

Comment: What result do you want to be produced?

Comment: @rhavendc rsult should be in some order like after 31st march it starts with 1 april,2 april...etc

Comment: @rhavendc  its oracle db

Comment: What data type is the `man_date_created` column? If that is a `date` column `trim()` doesn't make sense. `trim()` is for character columns, not for dates. If you want to get rid of the time, use `trunc()`. And if `man_date_created` is **not** a date, then why are you storing dates in a `varchar` column? Don't do that.

Answer (score 2):

You should convert your string in date

```
SELECT TO_DATE('12-4-2016','YYYY-MM-DD');



select trim(DATE(date,'YYYY-MM-DD'))as createddate,count(*) recordcount
from man 
where man_date_created>sysdate-15 
group by trim(man_date_created) ORDER BY createddate;
```

in your case try this

```
select DATE(mandate,'YYYY-MM-DD') createddate, count(*) recordcount, 
count(case when man_status = 'A' then 1 end) as a, 
count(case when man_status = 'S' then 1 end) as s, 
count(case when man_status = 'C' then 1 end) as c, 
count(case when man_status = 'R' then 1 end) as r 
from man 
where man_status IN ('A','S','C','R') and mandate>sysdate-15 
group bycreateddate ORDER BY createddate;
```

Comment: you have an error ..., please show it.. anyway i have update the answer with a light suggestion ..

Comment: hers it error its getting = ORA-00904: "STR_TO_DATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:

Comment: For oracle the sintax is different .. i have update the answer.. please don'ìt use all db tags..remove mysql

Comment: nope its not working..this is the query i am using

      select trim(DATE(mandate,'YYYY-MM-DD')) createddate,
       count(*) recordcount,
       count(case when man_status = 'A' then 1 end) as a,
       count(case when man_status = 'S' then 1 end) as s,
       count(case when man_status = 'C' then 1 end) as c,
       count(case when man_status = 'R' then 1 end) as r
from man 
where man_status IN ('A','S','C','R')and mandate>sysdate-15
group by trim(DATE(mandate,'YYYY-MM-DD')) ORDER BY createddate;

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the string to date in the ORDER BY clause:

```
select trim(date)as createddate,count(*) recordcount
from man 
where man_date_created>sysdate-15 
group by trim(man_date_created) ORDER BY TO_DATE(date, 'DD/Month/YYYY');
```